# psycopg2 successfully installed, but pip freeze does not show it

Tags: linux, django, amazon-ec2, pip, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 for my django app.

When i run `python manage.py collectstatic` i see `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2`.
Then I run `pip install psycopg2`, but after successful installation `pip freeze` does not see it. I have installed `libpq-devel` and `python-devel`.
What am i doing wrong?

I am using Linux AMI from Amazon (EC2), if it is important.

UPDATE:
i tried to `wget` source and install it like `python setup.py install`. Now i can `import psycopg2`, but still can't do it in virtualenv.

Comment: are you still getting the no module named error?

Comment: @doniyor, yes, no idea what's wrong, tried to install as root already. Gives me mistake, that there are no such package as pip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow, package was installed in directory `lib64`, but all other packages was installed in directory `lib`, so I copied `psycopg2` from `lib64` to `lib` and everything became all right.